# Using the assert macro while global variables are initialized

Tags: c++, c++11, assert, assertion

In the following code, the first `assert` does not compile because, in MSVC2015RC at least, it is defined essentially as `assert(expression) (void)(!!(expression))`.

```
int x = 1;
assert( x == 1 );
void foo()
{
    assert( x == 1 );
}
```

The error message is

> C2062 type 'void' unexpected

The second assert compiles without problems but it is not executed unless `foo()` is called. I would like to use `assert` while the global variables are being initialized. Is there are any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues here.

First, only declarations (e.g. variable, class, function) can go in global scope. `assert()` is not a declaration, that's why you can't do there.

That might lead to a workaround to just shove it into a declaration, like:

```
int x = 1;
namespace assert_x_is_1 {
    bool _ = (assert(x == 1), true);
}
```

On gcc, the above compiles fine and will assert if `x` is not 1. However, on clang, this leads to the second problem: `assert()` really wants to be used in a function - it uses a macro which is only defined in a function.

So for that, you could hack together a class declaration:

```
#define ASSERT_CLASS2(expr, ctr) namespace assert##ctr { struct Asserter { Asserter() { assert(expr); } } s; }
#define ASSERT_CLASS(expr) ASSERT_CLASS2(expr, __COUNTER__)

int x = 1;
ASSERT_CLASS(x == 1);
```

That will create a global variable in a semi-anonymous namespace that in its constructor will assert the expression. This works on both clang and gcc.

Answer (score 0):

in c/c++, statement such as

```
x==1
```

can't be wrote beyond function

```
assert( x == 1 );
```

will be replaced during precompiling

```
(void)(!!(x==1));
```

it is a statement, can't be wrote beyond function definition